# Нет перехода по ссылке при нажатии на картинку

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть 2 блока. Видео и Фото. В компьютерной версии когда нажимаешь на них, то происходит переход по ссылке, но в мобильной версии этот переход не работает, то есть они не кликабельны. В чем может быть проблема?
Вот CSS:

```
.media-links {
    width: 100%;
}
.media-links a {
    display: block;
    /*height: 190px*/
    ;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.media-links .video-link {
    background-image: url('../img/videos.png');
    margin-right: 10%;
}
.media-links .foto-link {
    background-image: url('../img/photos.png');
}
.media-links a {
    height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .media-links a {
        height: 260px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 45%;
    }
}
```

Вот html:

```
<div class="media-links">
<p><a class="video-link" href="/qalereya/video">&nbsp;</a> 
<a class="foto-link" href="/qalereya/foto-qalereya">&nbsp;</a></p>
</div>
```

Я думал может из-за того, чтобы блоки наезжают друг на друга. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: пропущен знак в открывающем теге `p` `p>` перед первой ссылкой

Comment: @fanfer перепроверил. не из-за этого

Comment: блок по которому клацаете должен быть внутри тега а

Comment: @Ljil  не совсем понял. можете на примере показать,? вы про media-links?

Comment: @asdas втолкните p внутрь a

Comment: @Ljil делал так, не получилось. внутрь обоих даже, все равно не работает

Comment: `.media-links a` вот здесь еще точка с запятой стоит не закомментированная

Comment: @fanfer тоже не помогло(